# Работа с памятью в Си

Tags: c, memory-management

Не понимаю.
Вывести номер ячейки памяти можно

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x = 0;
    printf("%x ", &x);
}
```

А вот вручную задать ни как

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x = 0;
    &x =0xCDFF00;
    printf("%x ", &x);
}
```

lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Либо как это сделать, я не в курсе. Поправьте или направьте на путь истинный...

Comment: У вас нет никакого "вывода номера ячейки памяти". Формат `%x` требует аргумента типа `unsigned int`, а вы передаете туда `int *`. Это чушь, а не "вывода номера ячейки памяти".

Comment: ... и что вообще за странная посылка вопроса? Вы можете вывести значение `2 + 2` и получить `4`. Однако вручную задать новое значение этой сумме как `2 + 2 = 5` вы не можете. Вас это удивляет? Если нет, то вас не должна удивлять и невозможность вашего "вручную задать" тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что применение операции взятия адреса `&` даёт нам rvalue-выражение. 
На [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/348198/) можно почитать, что это такое:

> lvalue (locator value) представляет собой объект, который занимает
>   идентифицируемое место в памяти (например, имеет адрес).
>
> rvalue определено путём исключения, говоря, что любое выражение
>   является либо lvalue, либо rvalue. Таким образом из определения lvalue
>   следует, что rvalue — это выражение, которое не представляет собой
>   объект, который занимает идентифицируемое место в памяти.

То есть это такое выражение, для которого не задано места в памяти, поэтому ему нельзя ничего присвоить. rvalue-выражением, например, является также константа `10`.

В то же время операция разыменования `*` возвращает lvalue-выражение. Если выражение является lvalue и не является `const`, то оно может стоять слева от присваивания. Поэтому, разыменовывая указатель, мы можем записать в память, на которую он указывает, новое значение:

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
*p = 15;
printf("%d\n", a); // 15
```

---

Вы не можете гарантированно записать значение по выбранному вами адресу. Хотя бы потому что этот адрес может быть уже занят чем-то другим.

Однако вы можете попросить операционную систему выделить вам память в нужном месте. Для этого в Unix есть системный вызов [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), а в Windows — функция [VirtualAlloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Заметьте, что эти вызовы не гарантируют выделение памяти по указанному адресу.

Учтите, что если вы вручную зададите значение указателю

```
char *p = (char*)0xCDFF00;
```

то его разыменование

```
*p = 0;
```

приведёт к неопределённому поведению в вашей программе. Поэтому так делать нельзя.

Comment: При программировании микроконтролеров `char *p = (char*)0xCDFF00;` такое обращение к памяти вполне возможно.

Comment: Мне наверно стоило начать  именно с микроконтроллеров. Как задавать значения регистров контроллера если нужен неросредственный доступ к конкретному адресу?